# How to pass variable as filename in subprocess.call(...) in Python?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, subprocess

I am trying to call the following commands in Python. Basically, I want to substitute the second filename with *customfilename*.

```
 customfilename = "this is me"
 call ("MP4Box -add video.h264 " + customfilename, shell=True)
```

I get the following error:

> > Error - 2 input names specified, please check usage

What is the correct way to pass a variable to the **call(....)** command?

Comment: 1. try `customfilename = "this is me" command= "MP4Box -add video.h264 " + customfilename
 call (command, shell=True)`. 2. From the syntax, I understood that we have to pass the arguments of the command as a list. `subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])`. reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html. so, try passing `MP4Box`,'-add'. 'video.h264', 'this is me' as a list.

Comment: Are you sure that resulting command line is correct? Try to *print "MP4Box -add video.h264 " + customfilename* and copy-paste it to command line. does it work as expected?

Comment: @Naveen Both list and string argument should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the filename in the string in quotes:

```
call ('MP4Box -add video.h264 "{}"'.format(customfilename), shell=True)
```